# Drupal Managing Content Module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Im looking for a module for drupal 7x that you can see all the content and folder structure within the admin panel.

Much appreciated

Comment: You mean a File/Directory Browser module?

Comment: an easier module to manage content, sort them and etc. and also allow to have multiple pages within a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a File/Directory Browser module for Drupal 7 then you can [check this link](https://drupal.org/project/webfm) or [this one](https://drupal.org/project/filebrowser).

**Edit:**

[WebFM](https://drupal.org/project/webfm) has not support for Drupal 7. But [this module: elFinder](https://drupal.org/project/elfinder) has.

Comment: Thanks, this would have been perfect if they had it for version 7

Comment: @jhel, please recheck my answer. Updated it.

Comment: Ok go it to work. how do I edit my content with this? meaning content that i have on a page

Comment: i'm looking for a module that will allow me to manage content as browsing content on the site NOT the source files. not sure if i make sense?

Comment: Login with your admin account and browse "`admin/content`" like "`http://example.com/admin/content`".